# how to resolve length exceeded exception in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm working on a website and i need to do the functionality for allowing a user to upload the videos. I tried doing it but at run time NetBeans came an error of max length exceeded i tried resolving it by writing max_allowed_packet=100 M in my.ini file in mysql but it did not help as it gave a message of access denied.
Can you please guide me how to get it fixed?

Comment: The problem is not from your NetBeans nor from your database, looks like your server doesn't allow too much traffic. Which configuration do you have for your file uploading (probably in your web.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.  Use the filesystem to store multi-megabyte videos, and use the database to store filenames and paths.  A huge video file in a database is also less efficiently served than a video stored directly in a file.  Webservers can make use of server calls like `sendfile` and `splice` to serve large files efficiently, but the database adds several copies and delays.

That being said, you need to set max_allowed_packet on both the client and server sides.